# Bad LCD? Bad microcontroller? Or what?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

So I recently bought an Arduino along with an LCD module and two extra ATmega328P-PU ICs. Yesterday it was working just fine then I disconnected everything and reconnected it and this happened.

What could possibly go wrong?

Setup:

[image: Photo of Arduino and 16 x 2 LCD display]

with microcontroller that came with the board:

Comment: with the microcontroller that a purchase separately:
http://s1072.photobucket.com/user/Tonny_Cassidy/media/Mobile%20Uploads/20160128_012325_zpslavooxa2.jpg.html?filters[user]=143082917&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1

Comment: Try wiggling all connections to make sure they are all properly seated in the breadboard and arduino-headers.

Comment: Also make sure that you actually connected all the wires up again properly to the right places. And then double check.

Comment: Are the wires soldered in place, or pushed into place? Instead of sending people off to PhotoBucket, how about posting the photos here as part of the question? You can embed photos into questions.

Answer (score 1):

> So i recently bought an arduino along with lcd module and 2 extra atmega328p-pu ,yesterday it was working just fine then i disconnect everything and reconnect it and this happen, what could possibly go wrong ?

I hope you understand how difficult it is for anyone to help with this type of question.

My quick answer is "follow the schematics and reconnect the wires correctly" and "double check all wires".

From the picture it looks like you need to adjust the LCD contrast and reduce the back-light. Please see typical schematics for this.

Another rule-of-thumb is to use wire colors in a meaningful way. For instance, black for GND, red for VCC, yellow for data, blue for control, green for clock, etc.

Cheers!

Comment: reconnected all the wires like 5 times,still the same,even tried changing the pin number that was connected to lcd on arduino,i find that my pin5 was dead so i change it to pin7,only half of the lcd working correctly ,and i have tried changing the contrast

Answer (score 1):

These 16x2 LCDs are fairly sensitive about their power requirements.

As a first step, I would check the VCC and GND wires are well connected, and closely connected on the breadboard near the LCD.

If your LCD display shows rubbish characters, check the 4 data lines are connected in the correct order.

Also it looks like the contrast is at minimum (or LED backlight at maximum).  It could just be the photo, but best check both of these.

Comment: it turns out that my board have dead pin(pin5),but even with new microcontroller ,only half of the display works as shown here http://s1072.photobucket.com/user/Tonny_Cassidy/media/Mobile%20Uploads/20160128_012325_zpslavooxa2.jpg.html?filters[user]=143082917&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1

Comment: Is it a simple bad solder joint?  Maybe just re-melting the solder will re-connect it.